# jquery open page in a tab and pass some POST values

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I open in a new window a php page and pass in some POST variable?
I am using jquery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would suggest creating an invisible form in your HTML like this:

```
<form id="invisible_form" action="new_window.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input id="new_window_parameter_1" name="parameter" type="hidden" value="default">
</form>
```

..and then submitting it via jQuery:

```
$('#new_window_parameter_1').val('value');
$('#invisible_form').submit();
```

Comment: You could also create the form with javascript append it to the body and then submit in order not to have it in the dom already.

Comment: Any way to do it without introducing form?

Answer (score 32):

Here is a sample how to submit a hidden form via POST:

```
function submit_post_via_hidden_form(url, params) {
    var f = $("<form target='_blank' method='POST' style='display:none;'></form>").attr({
        action: url
    }).appendTo(document.body);

    for (var i in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            $('<input type="hidden" />').attr({
                name: i,
                value: params[i]
            }).appendTo(f);
        }
    }

    f.submit();

    f.remove();
}
```

And to use it:

```
submit_post_via_hidden_form(
    'some link',
    {
        val1: val1,
        val2: val2
    }
);
```

Comment: BTW now I use this [plugin](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) to submit a hidden form. Not sure why, guess because of the issues with some specific browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Lite version with simple array compatibility:

```
    var url = 'myurl.html';
    var params = {
        inputId: 'somevalue',
        itemArray: ['as','a','example']
    };

    var f = $("<form target='_blank' method='POST' style='display:none;'></form>").attr({
        action: url
    }).appendTo(document.body);

    for (var i in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if($.isArray(params[i])) {
                for (var j in params[i]) {
                    $('<input type="hidden" />').attr({
                        name: i + '[]',
                        value: params[i][j]
                    }).appendTo(f);
                }
            } else {
                $('<input type="hidden" />').attr({
                    name: i,
                    value: params[i]
                }).appendTo(f);
            }
        }
    }

    f.submit();
    f.remove();
```