# jQuery open page in a new tab while passing POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a javascript variable called "list". I need to **send it as a POST data to another page and open that page in a new tab** (with the POST data present).

This code:

```
jQuery.post('datadestination.php', list);
```

sends the data all right, but ofcourse it opens the page in the same tab.

I saw some solutions to similar problems using invisible form and things like that, but I could not get them to work. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: The solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024040/jquery-open-page-in-a-tab-and-pass-some-post-values appears to work. Have you any specific problems with that? What happens?

Comment: You can also call a javascript function that dynamically creates a form with a `target='_blank'` attribute:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013109/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-firefox-in-dynamically-created-form-without

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest:

1. Pass that list with the `jquery.post()` function and save it in the `SESSION` array.
2. Open a new tab with the same file/address/URL with the `window.open()` function.
3. Retrieve saved data from the `SESSION` array.

This seems straightforward and clean to me.

Comment: This is accually brillant... Somehow I coudn't bare with this invisible form thing.

Comment: Dont so useful if user open multiple tabs and values of the form changes.

Answer (score 24):

You can send a form using the target="_blank" attribute.

```
<form action="datadestination.php" method="POST" target="_blank" id="myform">
  <input type="hidden" name="list" id="list-data"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in JS:

```
jQuery('#list-data').val(list);
jQuery('#myform').submit();
```

Comment: It opens one extra blank tab any idea what might be the reason?

Answer (score 18):

This is an implementation of Sergey's solution.

```
<?php // this is save.php
    session_start();
    // DO NOT just copy from _POST to _SESSION,
    // as it could allow a malicious user to override security.
    // Use a disposable variable key, such as "data" here.
    // So even if someone passed _POST[isAdmin]=true, all that he would do
    // is populate _SESSION[data][isAuthenticated], which nobody reads,
    // not the all-important _SESSION[isAuthenticated] key.
    if (array_key_exists('data', $_POST)) {
        $_SESSION['data']             = $_POST['data'];
        $_SESSION['data.timestamp']   = time();
        // Let us let the client know what happened
        $msg = 'OK';
    } else {
        $msg = 'No data was supplied';
    }
    Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    die(json_encode(array('status' => $msg)));
?>
```

In the first page:

```
$.post('save.php', { data: list }, function(response){
    if (!response.status) {
        alert("Error calling save");
        return;
    }
    if (response.status !== 'OK') {
        alert(response.status);
        return;
    }
    // We had a response and it was "OK". We're good.
    window.open('datadestination.php');
});
```

And in datadestination.php add the fix:

```
if (!array_key_exists('data', $_SESSION)) {
   die("Problems? Did you perchance attempt to reload the page and resubmit?"); 
   // For if he did, then yes, $_SESSION would have been cleared.

   // Same if he is operating on more than one window or browser tab.
}
// Do something to validate data. For example we can use data.timestamp
// to assure data isn't stale.
$age = time();
if (array_key_exists($ts = 'data.timestamp', $_SESSION)) {
    $age -= $_SESSION[$ts];
}
if ($age > 3600) {
    die("Data is more than one hour old. Did someone change server time?!?");
    // I actually had ${PFY} do that to me using NTP + --hctosys, once.
    // My own time zone is (most of the year) exactly one hour past GMT.
}

// This is safe (we move unsecurity-ward):
$_POST = $_SESSION['data'];
unset($_SESSION['data'], $_SESSION['data.timestamp']);
// keep things clean.

// From here on, the script behaves "as if" it got a _POST.
```

## Update

You can actually *merge* `save.php` and `datadestination.php` and use a "saving stub" `savepost.php` that you can recycle in other pages:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // DO NOT just copy from _POST to _SESSION,
    // as it could allow a malicious user to override security.
    // Use a disposable variable key, such as "data" here.
    if (array_key_exists('data', $_POST)) {
        // Timestamp sent by AJAX
        if (array_key_exists('ts', $_POST)) {
            // TODO: verify ts, but beware of time zones!
            $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
            Header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            die(json_encode(array('status' => 'OK')));
        }
        die("Error");
    }
    // This is safe (we move unsecurity-ward):
    $_POST = $_SESSION['data'];
    unset($_SESSION['data']); // keep things clean.
?>
```

Now your call becomes

```
$.post('datadestination.php', { data: list, ts: Date.now() }, function(){
    window.open('datadestination.php');
});
```

and in your `datadestination.php` (or anywhere else) you add

```
require 'savepost.php';
```

Comment: Kudos! I'd write it myself, but it's good for others who run into the same problem to see the working solution.

Comment: Och, I had somehow forgotten you wanted it to open in a *new* tab. Fixed.