# Can I open URL with POST using Karate UI?

Tags: karate

In [Karate UI](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core), can I open URL with POST?

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true }
Given driver 'https://example.com' # I want to open this URL with POST.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject any JavaScript into the page using `script()`.

So what I suggest is you can create an invisible form and then submit it. Or it might be simpler for you to host a special page for testing to do that.

Please see this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024101/143475